# How to move specific files from one subdirectory to the other

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, shutil

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
 Dataset
   ---> Images
          ----> n02085620-Chihuahua
                    ---> n02085620_01.jpg
                    ---> n02085620_02.jpg
                    .
                    .
                    . (~ 150+ files)
          ----> n02086646-Blenheim-Spaniel
          ----> n02087046-Toy-Terrier
          .
          .
          .
          (120 Folders)
   ---> Training
          ---> Chihuahua
          ---> Blenheim Spaniel
          ---> Toy Terrier
          .
          .
          .
          (120 Empty Folders)
```

I also have a list of file paths:

```
train_file_list = ['n02085620-Chihuahua/n02085620_5927.jpg', ... ', 'n02086646-Blenheim_spaniel/n02086646_1342.jpg', ..., 'n02087046-toy_terrier/n02087046_3490.jpg' ]
```

This list has 12,000 items, 100 file-paths for each of the 120 breeds *in order* i.e., the first 100 images are Chihuahua, next 100 are Blenheim-Spaniel and so on.

I also have a dictionary mapping `dog_id` to `dog_breed` constructed from two respective lists:

```
n02097658: Chihuahua
n02092002: Japanese Spaniel
n02099849: Maltese
.
.
.
(120 key-value pairs)
```

I am trying to loop through my file-path list and for every file-path that begins with `dog_id`, I want to move that file to its respective folder under `Dataset/Training` using the dictionary for mapping it to the breed.

Here's the code I've tried on ***Jupyter Notebook*** that doesn't seem to be working. Where am I going wrong? Please help!!!

```
root = "/Users/krithika/Desktop/GitHub Repositories/The-Pup-Files"

os.chdir(root)

for d_id, file in zip(dog_ids, train_file_list):
    if file.startswith(d_id):
        shutil.copy((root + "/Dataset/Images/" + file), (root + "/Dataset/Training/" + dog_ids_breeds[d_id]))
```

Comment: You need to give more description of your problem. "doesn't seem to be working" is not very helpful. What actually happened? Files not moved at all? Is there any exceptions? Where did you run your 'Jupyter Notebook'? On a remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try nesting your loops, like this:

```
for d_id in dog_ids:
    for file in train_file_list:
        if file.startswith(d_id):
            shutil.copy((root + "/Dataset/Images/" + file), (root + "/Dataset/Training/" + dog_ids_breeds[d_id]))
```

Hope this works! :-)

Comment: thank you soooooooo much!! I was working on this all day, you're a life-saver <3 <3